# Coffeescript with "#{}" makes rails so slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

My friend and I were coding a partial to be called in a view:

When user clicks on any button, a menu is shown, and after selecting something, he will be redirected to another page. That page is decided by the product number, something along the product/:id.

but when we used `"product/#{product.id}"` coffeescript of in our partial, The site became so slow, more than 7s to load it, but when we saved the product.id on a hidden text, it was loaded in less than 0.5s.

And the only change was this! except `"product/#{product.id}"` -> `"product/" + ${#sth}.val()`

Is there any reason for this?

--
Update:
This is the code I've used, I know it's so messy right now, cause we changed it a lot: But that's the idea

```
- if product.blank?
    - id = "new"
    - path = "#{new_software_path}/"
- else
    - id = product.id
    - path = product.getFileLink(:DASHBOARD_LINK)
.modal.hide.fade{:id => "role-options-#{id}","aria-hidden" => "true", "aria-labelledby" => "myModalLabel", :role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}
    .modal-header
        %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} ×
        %h3#myModalLabel choose a language
    .modal-body.profile_body
        %input{type: :hidden, class: id, value: path}   
        %select{class: id}
            %option{value: :en} English
            %option{value: :de} German
    .modal-footer
        %button.btn{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal"}= t("forms.close")
        %button.btn.btn-primary{"data-id" => id}= t("forms.submit")
:coffeescript
    $(".btn-primary").click ->      
        $id = "." + $(this).data("id")
        window.location.href = $("input." + $id).val() + $("select." + $id).val()
        alert(#{product.id});
```

---

My rails log shows:

With 'alert' part:

```
Started GET "/dashboard/softwares" for 127.0.0.1
Processing by SoftwaresController#manage as HTML
  Rendered shared/_otherlanguage.html.haml (141.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_otherlanguage.html.haml (150.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_otherlanguage.html.haml (149.3ms)
  ...
  Rendered shared/_otherlanguage.html.haml (139.8ms)
  Rendered softwares/manage.html.haml within layouts/dashboard (12869.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_dashboard_navigation.html.haml (2.4ms)

Completed 200 OK in 12922ms (Views: 12890.0ms)
```

Without 'alert' part:

```
Started GET "/dashboard/softwares" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-02 10:09:44 +0430
  Rendered shared/_otherlanguage.html.haml (145.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_otherlanguage.html.haml (3.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_otherlanguage.html.haml (0.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_otherlanguage.html.haml (0.8ms)
  ...
  Rendered shared/_otherlanguage.html.haml (0.8ms)
  Rendered softwares/manage.html.haml within layouts/dashboard (477.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_dashboard_navigation.html.haml (0.9ms)

Completed 200 OK in 577ms (Views: 549.6ms)
```

---

As I said, we created a partial that would get a 'product' object for locals, and used it to generate the link, when clicking submit.

Comment: Can't judge with little info. Better to post more code.

Comment: `"product/#{product.id}"` just compiles to the javascript `"product/" + product.id`, so this doesn't make much sense.  Why are you using a different variable between the two bits of code?

Comment: Where is this `product` variable coming from? How does it get into scope in your CoffeeScript?

Comment: Updated my question with the code, and related logs in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a note about this under the section "Caveats" at https://github.com/paulnicholson/coffee-filter that points out that the coffeescript compilation is not cached if there are ruby interpolations in it.  Presumably coffeescript is slow to compile.  I am seeing this slowness when I embed coffeescript with interpolation in haml templates.